# Getting an error working with Map Entry in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

This is the code that I've written

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map <Integer,String> map = new HashMap <Integer,String>();  

        map.put(100,"Amit");  
        map.put(101,"Vijay");  
        map.put(102,"Rahul");

        Set set = map.entrySet();
        Iterator i = set.iterator();
        Map.Entry hello;

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            hello = (Map.Entry) i.next();
        }

        System.out.println (hello.getValue());
    }
}
```

I am expecting the output to be "Rahul", but instead I'm getting an error in the `println` statement that the variable `hello` might not have been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `hello` will not be initialize if the Loop is not entered, that is why you get the error in the compiler, so Change line:

```
Map.Entry hello;
```

to

```
Map.Entry hello = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Local variables have to be initialized before being used.
To solve it, either set it to `null`. You could also declare the variable inside the `while` statement if you use it only in the `while`.

Besides, you should favor generic types to raw types.
It prevents unsafe casts as you did and makes your code more robust.

```
Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry = null;
while (i.hasNext()) {
   entry = i.next();  
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error `the variable _hello_ might not have been initialized` is because the variable `hello` was never initialized and there might be the cases when Map is empty and in that case it will never go inside the while loop.

If you really want to go deep into this matter, one whole chapter of the Java Language Specification is dedicated to the issue of [Definite Assignment](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/defAssign.html). Example:

> the rules do not accept the variation:

```
void flow(boolean flag) {
  int k;
  if (flag)
    k = 3;
  if (!flag)
    k = 4;
System.out.println(k);  // k is not "definitely assigned" before here
}
```

> and so compiling this program must cause a compile-time error to occur.

Similarly in your case variable `hello` is never initialized. Initializing it to `null` will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should look like

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map <Integer,String> map = new HashMap <Integer,String>();

        map.put(100,"Amit");
        map.put(101,"Vijay");
        map.put(102,"Rahul");

        Set set = map.entrySet();
        Iterator i = set.iterator();
        Map.Entry hello = null;

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            hello = (Map.Entry) i.next();
            System.out.println (hello.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```

Now you will see all the names of your map. :)

Comment: This is not what OP want